# mathematica in Konsole can't access last input with keyboard

Tags: command-line, programming, konsole, mathematica

Here is my configuration

```
       :-------------------::        ----------------------------- 
     :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      OS: Fedora 32 (Thirty Two) x86_64 
   /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Host: HP EliteBook 840 G5 
  :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Kernel: 5.6.15-300.fc32.x86_64 
 :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Uptime: 36 mins 
,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Packages: 6700 (rpm) 
:------------:MMMd-------    .---:   Shell: zsh 5.8 
:----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   DE: Plasma 
:-    -------:MMMd--------------:    WM: KWin 
:-   --------/MMMd-------------;     Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Adwaita [GTK2] 
:-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
:-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       Terminal: konsole 
:---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        Terminal Font: Monospace 11 
:------:://:-------------::          CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz 
:---------------------://            GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
```

I lauched mathematica in konsole, here is what I did to explan you the problem

```
➜  ~ bmathematica
Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= eq=x^2-1

              2
Out[1]= -1 + x

In[2]:= ^[[A
```

Until Out[1], everything is fine.
At In[2], I wanted to use the previous input :In[1], so I pressed the key "up" and I couldn't retrieve the input. Instead I have this character: `^[[A`

It happens with other program like matlab in console or maxima in console.

What is wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Have you tried running Mathematica from another Shell like Bash or Dash (`sh -c bmathematica`)?

Comment: I thought also but I have the same problem:

[smilia@localhost Executables]$ ./math
Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= eq=x^2+1

             2
Out[1]= 1 + x

In[2]:= ^[[A